# How to process the whole batch tensor in efficient way?

Tags: tensorflow

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.variable_scope('experiment'):
        a = tf.get_variable('a', [1000,24,128], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1) )
        b = tf.get_variable('b', [1000,15,128], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1) )
        c = tf.get_variable('c', [1000,24,15], dtype=tf.float32,  initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
        for i in range(1000):
            ai = tf.slice(a,[i,0,0],[1,-1,-1]) # (1,24,128)
            bi = tf.slice(b,[i,0,0],[1,-1,-1]) # (1,15,128)
            aii = tf.reshape(ai, [ int(ai.get_shape()[1]), int(ai.get_shape()[2])] ) # (24, 128)
            bii = tf.reshape(bi, [ int(bi.get_shape()[1]), int(bi.get_shape()[2])] ) # (15, 128)
            ci = contract_func(aii,bii) # (24,15)
            c[i] = ci
```

I want to process the two batch: a and b and product c. Batch size is 1000.
Every element ci is the contract result of ai and bi. The contract operation is defined by myself. 
But I am not sure whether it is an efficient way to do this? Is there any simple method ? Thanks.

Comment: Is `contract_fun` just the matrix product of `aii` and `bii` transposed?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to achieve can be done with just:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope('experiment'):
    a = tf.get_variable('a', [1000, 24, 128], dtype=tf.float32,
                         initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
    b = tf.get_variable('b', [1000, 15, 128], dtype=tf.float32,
                        initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
    c = tf.matmul(a, tf.transpose(b, (0, 2, 1)))
    # Since Python 3.5 you can also do
    # c = a @ tf.transpose(b, (0, 2, 1))
print(c.shape)
# TensorShape([Dimension(1000), Dimension(24), Dimension(15)])

# Test compute the value
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    c_value = sess.run(c)
print(c_value.shape)
# (1000, 24, 15)
```